# Change text of input in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input/textbox in Bootstrap that I would like to fill with a certain string, by default.

By this I do not mean using the `placeholder` attribute, but actually changing the default text of the input, so  that it can be selected/edited by the user.

Example: (Box filled automatically on page load)

[image: http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/5189/6tqs.png]

The content is not changing, so if it does not need to be done programmatically, if it can be done through HTML that would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have that text in the **value** attribute of the input tag!

Comment: Wow, I was trying every tag like `text`, `default`, etc. That was simple :) Forgot they work like regular textboxes.

Comment: if you're using a textarea, make sure the text is in between the opening and closing <textarea> tags!